# Why is Trend Micro Maximum Security constantly read/write to disk in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hp-laptop

Trying to fix a laptop that recently upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1.  Problem with the laptop is that if Windows 10 starts in normal mode, there is always constant disk IO activty, the mouse pointer flicks between the normal arrow, and the one with the blue cycle for background processing. This causes the mouse to lose focus making it difficult to select some screen elements and to highlight text.

Checked the laptop specs - Cpu and RAM all good for Windows 10.

Monitored Task Manager. The application/process doing the IO is Trend Micro Maximum Security Suite. However Trend is not conducting any scans.

Start Win 10 in safe mode and Trend Micro does not start, and the constant disk IO does not occur.

Trend Micro's support site does not have any info. Searching for Windows 10 issues of constant disk activity have not yielded any useful results either.

What is the cause? Apart from uninstalling Trend Micro, is there another solution to beat this?

Comment: Is that version of Trend compatible with Windows 10?

Comment: According to Trend Micro, yes

Comment: All I can suggest is to uninstall it completely and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Appears that Task Manager lies. Found someone with similar problem. Turns out of you drill down to Resource Monitor,  the info can be totally different.

It was HPs SimplePass which has conflicts with Windows 10. Uninstalled SimplePass and the problem went away.

For Info: SimplePass is used for fingerprint scanning.